LinkedIn send connection request and send message to a user(using user ID) using nodejs
I want to create a nodejs script in nodejs which should send the connection request and then message to a user using the LinkedIn user's ID.
I have already created developer's app and i have client id and secret. And in later process I just got confused that how to send connection request and message using the oauth flow as I'm not going to use any redirect url since it doesn't has any frontend.
Step1: login/get access token of my account
Step2: send connection request to my friend's account using his ID.
How to achieve it?
I tried LinkedIn official documentation to generate access token and I didn't get access token.
